# Get KeyCode for button click reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the keyCode for a button click but the e returns undefined below is code for reference https://codesandbox.io/s/345v7n57zp

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <MyButton />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

function myButtonClicked(e) {
  e.persist();
  console.log(e);
  console.log(this, "Button Clicked");
}

function MyButton() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={myButtonClicked} >Click 1</button>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Issue was resolved after checking on browser experience https://345v7n57zp.codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <MyButton />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

myButtonClicked(e) {
  e.persist();
  console.log(e);
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  console.log(this, "Button Clicked");
}

MyButton() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.myButtonClicked.bind(this)} >Click 1</button>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: not working, this.myButtonClicked.bind(this) , myButtonClicked is not in scope of MyButton